# Rails Geokit Too Many Queries Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geokit

I was trying to do a little app to test the gem "geokit", "~> 1.8.4"

It was working at the beginning but then started raising this error

> Geokit::Geocoders::TooManyQueriesError

at most I did 100 queries with this line of code

> suggested_bounds = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode(params[:location])

Can anyone help me

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has a limit of 2,500 requests per 24 hour period.

I think they also restrict it if you do too many in a short like (like many within a second).

Are you doing that many in a short period (e.g. many in a second)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not doing that in a short period.
I am trying to figure out what is happening. I registered a user, but stills the same, before I was doing anonymus. I am not sure if the problem is because the google limit or Geocoders.

Comment: Seems that I did too many in a short time, because 24 hs later is working again. Thank you.