# Geokit first time finds the address and when we ran this again it will not find the address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geokit

I m using a `geokit` and `geokit-rails` gem. when i m finding the address it give me below warning.

`An error has occurred during geocoding: Geokit::TooManyQueriesError`

`Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode( "Flagler Beach, FL, US")`. Tried this on console. first time it find the address and when we ran this again it will not find the address for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Geokit Too Many Queries Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347517/rails-geokit-too-many-queries-error)